# Facebook Integration in IOS to fetch users data

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had registered my application in facebook developers. I got app id and client key.

Is there any tutorials for an application to fetch users data?

Any third parties suggested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why third party? What's wrong with Facebooks documentation? It's perfectly clear

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is the best for me http://www.raywenderlich.com/44640/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-1